# Transaction problem in RStudio for tweet apriori analysis

Tags: r, transactions

I want to use the apriori algorithm to apply association rules between words on the tweet database I have with RStudio. However, the code below gives an error on a million rows of data, while working on a small number of data. I needed your help as I couldn't understand what caused the error.

```
TweetTrans <- read.transactions("../input/tweets/output.csv", 
                            rm.duplicates=FALSE,
                            format = "basket",
                            sep = ",",
                            encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The Error is:

```
Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class “ngCMatrix” object: row indices are not sorted within columns
Traceback:
1. read.transactions("../input/tweets/output.csv", rm.duplicates = FALSE, 
 .     format = "basket", sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8")
2. as(data, "transactions")
3. asMethod(object)
4. new("transactions", as(from, "itemMatrix"), itemsetInfo = data.frame(transactionID = names(from), 
 .     stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
5. initialize(value, ...)
6. initialize(value, ...)
7. callNextMethod()
8. .nextMethod(.Object = .Object, ... = ...)
9. callNextMethod()
10. .nextMethod(.Object = .Object, ... = ...)
11. as(from, "itemMatrix")
12. asMethod(object)
13. new("ngCMatrix", p = c(0L, p), i = as.integer(i) - 1L, Dim = c(length(levels(i)), 
  .     length(p)))
14. initialize(value, ...)
15. initialize(value, ...)
16. callNextMethod()
17. .nextMethod(.Object = .Object, ... = ...)
18. validObject(.Object)
19. stop(msg, ": ", errors, domain = NA)
```

Comment: It sounds like a rogue line in your data file - perhaps with a wrong separator or a missing quote. You could try splitting the file into chunks as a way of narrowing down where the problem might be, or perhaps read it in as text using `scan` or `readLines` and run a few tests on it.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Actually, I tried to break it into smaller pieces, but because the data is too much, I have to split it into thousands of pieces. I thought it might be related to a wrong separator as you mentioned, but could it also be due to a lack of memory? Or is it possible to capture exactly the line in the data where it gives the error?

Comment: It could be a memory problem, I suppose. Let's hope not!  I have added an answer with a few ideas that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas for how to find a rogue line in the data file.  The input to `read.transactions` should be a text file the looks something like

```
A, B, C
B, C
C, D, E
D, A, B, F
```

where A, B ,C, etc are the names of the items (probably longer than one character each!)

So you could read in the file using `readLines`...

```
data <- readLines("../input/tweets/output.csv")
```

Each element of `data` (one per line of the file) should be a string of the form `"A, B, C"` etc, as above.

You could then use functions (e.g. from the `stringr` package) to check if any lines contain unusual characters, or have an odd format.  Without seeing your file, it is hard to say how to do this, but you might, for example, look for quotes in odd places (`str_detect(data, '\\"')`) or characters that are not letters, digits , spaces or commas (`str_detect(data, "[^\\w\\d\\s,]")`).

Another thing you could try is to write a `for` loop to take each element of `data` (or perhaps larger chunks if that is too slow), save it as a file, try reading it with `read.transactions`, and see where it crashes.

```
for(i in seq_along(data)){
   writeLines(data[i], "dummyfile.csv")
   trans <- read.transactions("dummyfile.csv", 
                              rm.duplicates=FALSE,
                              format = "basket",
                              sep = ",",
                              encoding = "UTF-8")
   }
```

The value of `i` when it crashes will give you the problem row number.  It might take a long time to run, though!

Comment: Unfortunately no result. But i think you are right with looking more carefully for the line which is not in the right structure. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One more thought - if you type `read.transactions` to get the source code of that function, you could copy it and try stepping through it in the console to see where the problem lies. You could change some of the default parameters - e.g. to make them more verbose. I guess the error is being generated in the `ngT <- new("ngTMatrix"...` line - something to do with the values of `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem: the same error got triggered when trying to cast a `list` to a `transaction` object.

I also couldn't easily figure out what lines in the data caused the issue, as it seems to be triggered by a combination of transactions and not necessarily by any individual one, but I managed to track down the source of the problem in this assignment ([source](https://github.com/mhahsler/arules/blob/b76621e49a8193047d30c64976a846370786f219/R/itemMatrix.R#L164)):

```
p <- new("ngCMatrix", p   = c(0L, p),
  i   = as.integer(i) - 1L,
  Dim = c(length(levels(i)), length(p)))
```

My R got pretty rusty over time and I couldn't find an immediate way to patch the code, but I came up with an alternative solution for constructing the `ngCMatrix` object:

- Assume you have the data in a data.frame following some sort of (`user`, `item`) format - in your case it would most likely be (`tweet_id`, `term/word`)
- Create a unique incremental ID for every `user` and `item` and add it to your data.frame
- Use those ID to create the sparse matrix and - optionally - enrich it with the labels for `item` and `user` to make it more interpretable
- Finally, cast the sparse matrix to a `transaction` object

Example (I implemented mine with data.table, but a traditional dataframe implementation would be very similar):

```
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)
library(arules)

DT <- data.table(user = c('A','A','B','B','A','C','D'), 
                 item = c('AAB','AAA','AAB','BBB','ABA','BBB','AAB'))

# Create user_ids
unique_users <- unique(DT$user)
users <- data.table(user=unique_users,
                    user_id=c(1:length(unique_users)))

# Repeat for items
unique_items <- unique(DT$item)
items <- data.table(item=unique_items,
                    item_id=c(1:length(unique_items)))

# Add indexes to original data table (setting keys helps with performance)
DT <- merge.data.table(x=DT, y=users, by='user')
DT <- merge.data.table(x=DT, y=items, by='item')

# Create the sparse matrix
mat <- sparseMatrix(
      i = DT$item_id, 
      j = DT$user_id, 
      dims = c(nrow(items), nrow(users)), 
      dimnames = list(items$item, users$user)
    ) 

# transform to arules 'transactions'
txn <- as(op, "transactions")
```

Please note that this doesn't help understanding what caused the issue, but rather provides a workaround to solve it. In my data.table implementation the code is pretty performant, taking only a few seconds to process over 30M transactions on a laptop-sized machine (2 CPUs, 16gb RAM).